# GWT and MySQL: What to use instead of App Engine?

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, gwt

I'm implementing a web application with GWT 2.1 and Eclipse 3.4.2 and I use MySQL as database.
The client-server-communication is working, but when I try to connect from the server to the database I get a MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. If I try to connect to the database directly without server, everything works fine.

As I found out GWT does not allow database connections if running with App Engine.
But if I turn off the App Engine, I get a lot of errors without knowing how to fix them.
What should I use instead of App Engine and how to do so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry, but this question makes no sense.  i voted to close.  maybe you can try explaining what exactly you're trying to do, what you have tried, what your experience with programming is, etc...

Answer (score 1):

GWT is a client-side technology. It translates your Java code to Javascript which then runs inside your browser. You can not directly connect to databases from javascript so you can not use any database connections directly in GWT.

AppEngine is a cloud solution that runs a limited version of Java. It does not support any SQL databases. The only database it supports (at the moment) is their own Datastore.

If you use GWT and MySql then the only option is to use a servlet server. Then GWT would RPC to servlet and servlet would connect to MySql database.

Here is an example: [project_MySQLConn](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/wiki/project_MySQLConn)